# Iterating through array using for loop - keeps failing?

Tags: java, arrays, iteration

(Hello world level tester here)
I've got a java application to delete a bunch of files post tests to keep everything clean, however the issue is I can't seem to get it to work, this is my first time touching on an array and it's a slightly more complex one than the ones they show in the tutorials, any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
    String[] fileArray;
    fileArray = new String[8];

    fileArray[0] = "/Downloads/file1.csv";
    fileArray[1] = "/Downloads/file2.csv";
    fileArray[2] = "/Downloads/file3.csv";
    fileArray[3] = "/Downloads/file4.csv";
    fileArray[4] = "/Downloads/file5.csv";
    fileArray[5] = "/Downloads/file6.csv";
    fileArray[6] = "/Downloads/file7.csv";
    fileArray[7] = "/Downloads/file8.csv";

    String home = System.getProperty("user.home");
    File filePath = new File(home+fileArray); 
    System.out.println(filePath);

    for (String count: fileArray) {
    if (filePath.exists()) {
        filePath.delete();
        System.out.println("Deleted");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("failed");
        Assert.fail();
    }
    System.out.println(count);
    }
```

Comment: wrape your code in try catch and please put what exception or error you got

Comment: What do you think `File filePath = new File(home+fileArray); ` does?

Comment: @Chief I was thinking I can use that as the directory and use that for iteration, I was wrong :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should concat new file path for every element in an array, so need to put work with a file in `for` body. So in every iteration, you get in variable `filePath` next element of an array and then you need to concat this variable to base path `home + filePath`. Now you are looking at needed file, you can create `file` object and work with it.

```
String[] fileArray;
fileArray = new String[8];

fileArray[0] = "/Downloads/file1.csv";
fileArray[1] = "/Downloads/file2.csv";
fileArray[2] = "/Downloads/file3.csv";
fileArray[3] = "/Downloads/file4.csv";
fileArray[4] = "/Downloads/file5.csv";
fileArray[5] = "/Downloads/file6.csv";
fileArray[6] = "/Downloads/file7.csv";
fileArray[7] = "/Downloads/file8.csv";

String home = System.getProperty("user.home");


for (String filePath: fileArray) {
    File file = new File(home + filePath); 
    System.out.println(filePath);
    if (file.exists()) {
        file.delete();
        System.out.println("Deleted");
    } else {
        System.out.println("failed");
        Assert.fail();
    }
}
```

Seem like you expect that in variable `count` you will see a number of iterated files. In this case, it does not work like this. Such form of `for` acting like this: `for (String arrayElement : arrayToWorkWith)` - mean that on every iteration in variable `arrayElement` will be put next element from array `arrayToWorkWith`. If you need to count number of element during iterations you can introduce separate variable and increment it or use another form of `for` cycle - `for (int i = 0; i < fileArray.length; i++)`.

Answer (score 0):

try it this way

```
 String[] fileArray;
    fileArray = new String[8];

    fileArray[0] = "/Downloads/file1.csv";
    fileArray[1] = "/Downloads/file2.csv";
    fileArray[2] = "/Downloads/file3.csv";
    fileArray[3] = "/Downloads/file4.csv";
    fileArray[4] = "/Downloads/file5.csv";
    fileArray[5] = "/Downloads/file6.csv";
    fileArray[6] = "/Downloads/file7.csv";
    fileArray[7] = "/Downloads/file8.csv";

    String home = System.getProperty("user.home");
    //File filePath = new File(home+fileArray);  thats wrong here and will give you a invalid file anyway as you concatenating a string with an object


    for (String file: fileArray) {
    File filePath = new File(home+file); //here you need to define the file
    if (filePath.exists()) {
        filePath.delete();
        System.out.println("Deleted");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("failed");
        Assert.fail();
    }
    System.out.println(file);
    }
```

Comment: It won't compile - as you delete `count` variable but still output it.

Comment: @sphinks Thanks, that was bad factoring. I renamed the variable now.